# login directory missing inside Solace pubsubplus pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, solace, solace-mq

I installed solacepubsubplus in my Kubernetes cluster using helm chart provided by Solace, and my solace pod came into running state as well. It has a service with multiple nodeports, out of which I used the nodeport targetting the login page port (8080). I got '404 not found' error on browser and this in solace pod logs

"2023/06/16 12:59:56 [error] 558#558: *174 open() "/usr/sw/loads/currentload/www/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.244.0.0, server: , request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1", host: ":32754""

How do I create login page for solace? Or should it have been there by default and there is something wrong with the installation.

I tried creating login directory through solace CLI but was unable to.